# Clarification about List<T> and WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I'm fairly new to WCF's and would like a bit of clarification. I'm attempting to return a `List<T>` from my WCF but I get an error when I try to consume it. Cannot conver `T[]` to a type of `List<T>`. Sample Below.

**Question:** Is this because WCF's can be consumed by multiple technologies and converts to an array?

Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface I_UI_Service
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Site> Get_Sites(string ntid);
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class Site
{
    public Site(int id, string description)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Description = description;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
    public List<Site> Get_Sites(string ntid)
    {
        List<Site> returnList = new List<Site>();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "SPROC_Name";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NTID", ntid);
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DB_ConnectionString()))
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    returnList.Add(new Site(Convert.ToInt16(reader["SiteID"]), reader["SiteDescription"].ToString()));
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

Consuption using List: (Error)

```
    List<Site> _Sites;

    public List<Site> Sites
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Sites == null)
            {
                UI_Data.I_UI_ServiceClient sc = new UI_Data.I_UI_ServiceClient();
                _Sites = sc.Get_Sites("MyInfo");
            }
            return _Sites;
        }
    }
```

Consuption using T[ ]: (Makes it work and why my question)

```
    Site[] _Sites;

    public Site[] Sites
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Sites == null)
            {
                UI_Data.I_UI_ServiceClient sc = new UI_Data.I_UI_ServiceClient();
                _Sites = sc.Get_Sites("MyInfo");
            }
            return _Sites;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure `<List>Site` is a typo yes?

Comment: Yes sorry should be `List<Site>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WCF serializes generic lists as arrays, but you can convert them back into generic lists by clicking the advanced button when you add the service reference (you'll see the drop downs are populated with array by default, but you can change them to lists).

When you use this option, the arrays sent across the wire will be converted into generic lists for you to consume. It doesn't change how the information is sent.

Comment: Thank you, Thats what I figured WCF was serializing the data as an array. That's an awesome option to convert to list, that makes it work the way I needed it to.

Comment: For those that may be new like myself, you can right click on the service reference and click configure reference to get the option to change the "Collection Type" to list. You don't have to re-add the service reference.